# Storing Large dataset for processing and analysis of data

Tags: dataset, data-analysis, data-formats, processing, data-engineering

I am new to data engineering and wanted to know , what is the best way to store more than 3000 GB of data for further processing and analysis ? I am specifically looking for open source resources . I have explored many data formats for storage . The dataset that I want to store is a heart rate pulse data generated by a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format of the data. A brief overview of your options with their pros and cons.

- **csv** - easily processed and shared, can be search from the terminal with `grep` will be limited after a few dozen of Gbs. Maybe you can break down your dataset into several `csv`s. (`json` will also fall into this category)
- **SQL database** - if the data is structured and follows a data schema, a traditional SQL database (like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)) can be an interesting option. SQL provides an expressive way to retrieve data and a PostgreSQL DB will totally handle 3 Tb data with the appropriate hardware + configuration. Lots of programming languages offer way to integrate with a SQL database like PostgreSQL or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).
- **No SQL database** - if the data is not structured or does not follow a data schema, tools like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) can store "key/values" or "documents". A No SQL DB will be able to handle 3 Tb of data with the appropriate hardware and cluster configuration.
- **Time series database** - you mention heart rate pulse data, this is likely to be time-series data. You might take a look at db specialized into storing time-series. [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-database/) would be my go-to if the timeseries dimension is the defining feature of the problem you want to solve.

---

Note: As you say you're getting started with data engineering, this book will provide you with valuable content on how to build data pipeline and select the appropriate tool. [Designing Data-Intensive Applications, by Martin Kleppmann](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23463279-designing-data-intensive-applications)

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the use cases - read vs write vs analytics etc. Nonetheless, you may want to explore [Hadoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) if not done already.